# uploading image to server in iphone and show progress bar....?

Tags: iphone, progress-bar

i am making an app in which i have to upload an image/video file to the server...i want to know what things i needed to do this..?and i also have to show the progress bar while image is uploading...how can i do this..?

can you write some code snippet on how to upload file to server...?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using http to transfer files.Allseeing-i have a great api for this called [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), its feature rich, well documented, easy to use and it supports file  [transfer tracking](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#progress).

They have code examples and a description on how to include it in your projects.